# how you would write this pymongo/mongodb query, in a way it inclues strings inside an array? (image included)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i wanna make a query looking for all documents that have, in their respective havelists, say, string1, string3, string4

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvwfB.png

#### Edit

I made some progress, i found that if i make this query

```
j = USERS_COLLECTION.find({ 'havelist.0.1': card}, {'havelist':1, 'position':1,'_id':1})
```

it works, but the issue is that i might eventually have to search on havelist.0.1, havelist.1.1, havelist.2.1, ..., havelist.n.1

Comment: ok, let me see if I undertsand your problem because it is a little unclear. 

Do you want a document to be returned if **the second element (element at index 1) matches the given _card_ for any element in the havelist or for all the elements in the havelist**??. Splitting the question. First, will you check only the second element? Second, the document should be returned if **at least one element** in its havelist satisfies the condition (being equal to the card) _or_ if **all elements** in the havelist matches the conditon?

Please, explain carefully

Comment: other elements inside will be checked also and the document should be returned only if some (i think 4 or 5) of those fields match given parameters (simultaneously), but i think that if you tell me how to perform this recursive(?) search that is described as havelist.0.1, havelist.1.1, havelist.2.1, ..., havelist.n.1, i think i get it. edit: i want the document to be returned if the second element matches the given card for ANY element in the havelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, David, try this:

```
users = USERS_COLLECTION.find({{'havelist': {'$elemMatch': { '1': card }}}}, {'havelist':1, 'position':1,'_id':1})
```

Such query uses `$elemMatch` query operator, which matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) is the official documentation of `$elemMatch` operator of MongoDB

Let me know if this worked, otherwise, tell me what went wrong.